# Google app engine return error log: unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jakarta-ee

I've just build a sample application to test out google app engine and google web toolkit feature, using a RPC service and google app engine with JDO. The service works on local. But after i deploy it to GAE and run, it show me the error as title says.
I use JRE7 to complie the application.
Here is my error log:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gwt/myexample/server/EmployeeServiceImpl:
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-e8c21a25e91f709f(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
   (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext
 (TraceContext.java:449)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run
 (TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.
 runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.
 runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

My application link: http://jdodemo02.appspot.com/
Any suggestion please ):

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compile your application with Java SE 6. GAE doesn't support Java SE 7. Locally it works, because the GAE simulator runs on top of your local JDK.

Comment: Wew, finally i did it, thanks for your support. In fact, i changed to JRE6 to complie the project before, still got the error because i forgot to change JDK from 1.7 to 1.6 too (JRE6 doesnt support JDK 1.7). Hope this help for someone who need :3

Answer (score 3):

One thing is to set the JRE 6 to the Build Path and the Compiler as well.
Dont forget, once you created your GAE Web Application project with a different JRE or JDK, always check the java version in the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` in your `.settings` folder.

Answer (score 3):

instead of directly editing the **org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml** in your **.settings** folder It will be better review it in eclipse as bellow

Right click on your eclipse project

Select **Properties**

Select **"Project Facets"** in the left panel

Select the Java version appropriately

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting for days. I have a Mac and needed to use GCM developing an Android app. The only way I could get GAE working in Android Studio, and also compatible with the installed JVM that I had was:

- Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).
- Customize it with [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) (`brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask`).
- Install Java using homebrew cask (`brew cask install java`).
- Install Android Studio using homebrew cask (`brew cask install android-studio`).
- Update Studio to the latest version.
- Go to settings of the project in Studio and change the target JDK to the one that homebrew installed (1.8 located in /Library/Java/Home, which is actually a symlink).

Hope non of you guys run in the same path as I did, One just doesn't walk into Mordor, It has been 5 long days of fighting.

Answer (score 0):

Too run creatjs project from Flash devlop you must downlod:
google compiler from link:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/
haxe compiler from
http://haxe.org/download
jave jre 7